# Django/ python-social-auth: LinkedIn extra data returns null on some fields

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth to retrieve LinkedIn profile data in Django.

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with LinkedIn</a>
```

is the link to login with LinkedIn.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'), ('firstName', 'first_name'), ('lastName', 'last_name'), ('email-address', 'email_address'), ('positions', 'positions'), ('summary', 'summary'), ('headline', 'headline'), ('picture-url', 'picture_url'),
                       ('site-standard-profile-request', 'site_standard_profile_request'), ('public-profile-url', 'public_profile_url'), ('location', 'location'), ('interests', 'interests'), ('skills', 'skills'), ('languages', 'languages'),]
```

However, when I check the extra data, it returns only the first name, last name, access token and id correctly. Everything else is null.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this as I am having the same problem :(

Comment: Same problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

The settings to obtain the extra data must be in the following format:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_SELECTORS = [
    'public-profile-url',
    'email-address',
    'interests',
    'skills',
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
```